# Why class with destructor is not trivially move constructible?

Tags: c++, destructor, type-traits, moveabletype

Why is this class:

```
class test_type {
public:
    ~test_type() {
        std::cout << "~()\n";
    }
};

// fails
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<test_type>, "");
```

not trivially move constructible?

Comment: Are you asking for the mechanism that leads to there not being a trivial move constructor, or are you asking for the reasoning  behind designing the language that way?

Comment: I'm asking why defining destructor makes a class not trivially move constructible. The name would suggest that only defining move constructor would make class not trivial in that aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why class with destructor is not trivially move constructible?

Because the standard says so:

> [class.prop]
>
> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator ([special], [class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]),
> - where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial, and
> - **that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor ([class.dtor]).**

Comment: Thanks. And do you know why do such a thing - why include destructor in moveable trait (or copyable)?

Comment: @HubertObrzut Typically, destructor calls need to be paired with constructor calls. Trivial copyability means that you can create copies without calling a constructor. As far as I can tell, this rule prevents some obviously broken programs without preventing anything useful.

Comment: The quote is for trivially copyable, but the question was asked about trivially move constructible.

Answer (score 0):

`is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>` is defined to be `is_trivially_constructible_v<T, T&&>` [[meta.unary.prop]](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:meta.unary.prop)

`is_trivially_constructible_v<T, T&&>` is by defined to be `is_constructible_v<T, T&&>` and the "variable definition for `is_constructible_v` is known to call no operation that is not trivial.

`is_construcible_v<T, T&&>` is defined to be true if and only if the variable definition is well-formed [[meta.unary.prop/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#8):

```
T t(declval<T&&>());
```

Only the validity of the immediate context of the variable initialization is considered.

With that knowledge, is `is_constructible_v<T, T&&>` true? Yes. A destructor [inhibits](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#8) the defaulted move constructor. But it [does not inhibit](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#6) the defaulted copy constructor. That is deprecated, but probably will never change. The variable definition is a copy construction, and is well-formed.

Does the definition call an operation that is not trivial? The copy constructor is trivial. The definition doesn't call a destructor. So, it is known that all operations are trivial.

**Therefore, I think `is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>` is true.** (and your compiler has a bug)

See also: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2827